# First-chance exception with Intel Parallel Debugger Extension (libiomp5md)/IPP 7 and VS2005

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2005, intel-ipp

Apparently when linking a library build with the Intel Composer 12.1 or against the IPP 7.0 under Visual Studio 2005, I always get this output in the Debug Output window:

> "First-chance exception at 0x7c812afb (kernel32.dll) in vasl_td.exe: 0xA1A01DB1: 0xa1a01db1."

According to

> http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/parallel-debugger-extension-exceptions-0xa1a01db1-0xa1a01db2/

this exception is wanted and used by the Intel parallel debugger add-in.
Apperently VS2005 does not handle these exceptions correctly. The solution mentioned at the link

> (Debug>Exceptions...>Win32 Exceptions and enabling Intel Parallel Extension Exceptions 0, 1 and 2)

is not working for everyone here, as the Intel Composer is not installed on each machine (VS2005 is).

The exception is annoying and also this introduces a new dependency to libiomp5md.dll that I wish to have removed.

Can I deactivate this "feature" at the Intel Composer? How do I deactivate this feature when using IPP 7?

Comment: I am curious did you get answer as what this exception is all about, I only get it on application termination (on VS2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding libiomp5md.dll, this is a dependency of ippi-core-7.0.dll, so any binary built against just IPP 7 will ultimately need the libiomp5md.dll as well.  This DLL is the OpenMP runtime library used by various Intel software products, including IPP.  So, this DLL is not specific to Composer.

About the link exception, I cannot give any advice on that other than try your darnedest to get your office to move to Visual Studio 2010 (and Windows 7 for that matter).

Comment: Thanks, but is there no ippi-core-7.0.dll without this restriction?

Comment: @OliverZendel - Unfortunately not, so you will have to deploy libiomp5md.dll along with the ippi DLLs.  However, you don't have to actually use the OpenMP features of IPP, to disable that, call `ippSetNumThreads(1)` before calling any other IPP functions.

Comment: Looks like this is not possible, I accept your answer as the correct one. Also we finally stopped using VS2005 :)